# Align Center Custom Navigation with Bootstrap 3 Grid System

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble aligning the my custom navigation to the center of the page using bootstrap grid system and keeping it consistent when changing screen sizes.

[image: Desktop Size]

Can anyone tell me the correct way of aligning these boxed `<div>`'s to the center of each screen widith (Phone, Tablet, Desktop) using Bootstrap 3 grid system.

**HTML**

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <nav role="navigation">
                            <!-- Button Left -->
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                                <div class="center-block">
                                    <div class="nav-box">
                                        <a href="" class="nav"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
                                    </div>




                                <!-- Button Center -->

                                    <div class="nav-box">
                                        <a href="" class="nav"><strong>ACHIEVEMENTS</strong></a>
                                    </div>



                                <!-- Button Right -->

                                    <div class="nav-box">
                                        <a href="" class="nav"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav> 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.center-block` user `.text-center` and give `display: inline-block` for `.nav-box`

Below is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/kc830h4j/1/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to center the text. The column is centered. Try adding `text-center` instead of `center-block`.

Here's a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0184v2h9/

```
            <div class="row">
                <nav role="navigation">
                    <!-- Button Left -->
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <div class="nav-box">
                                <a href="" class="nav"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
                            </div>




                        <!-- Button Center -->

                            <div class="nav-box">
                                <a href="" class="nav"><strong>ACHIEVEMENTS</strong></a>
                            </div>



                        <!-- Button Right -->

                            <div class="nav-box">
                                <a href="" class="nav"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav> 
            </div>
```

You can manipulate the grid system using additional classes, for example you could use "`col-lg-12 col-sm-6`" which would make it a 12 width column on a large screen, and a 6 width on a small screen.

Hope that helps!

Comment: `text-center` only aligns the text to the center of the div box, which is already center.

Comment: @AndrewC.Duarte The code you provided has the text hugging the left side of the centered div. If you want the contents centered, text-center will align it to the middle of it. col-lg-10 and col-lg-offset-1 only centers its container.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.new_apply{
     text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="row new_apply">
                        <nav role="navigation">
                            <!-- Button Left -->
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                                <div class="center-block">
                                    <div class="nav-box">
                                        <a href="" class="nav"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
                                    </div>




                                <!-- Button Center -->

                                    <div class="nav-box">
                                        <a href="" class="nav"><strong>ACHIEVEMENTS</strong></a>
                                    </div>



                                <!-- Button Right -->

                                    <div class="nav-box">
                                        <a href="" class="nav"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav> 
                    </div>
```

and here is the JSfidle

[DEmo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnLoz6Lp/)